# Does Canonical provide rootfs tarballs for Ubuntu Core anymore?

Tags: ubuntu-core

We used to find recent builds at https://partner-images.canonical.com/core/ but that last build available there now is from June of 2023. Since then, I would have expected newer versions to have been made available.

I found [more recent builds of ubuntu-core](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/22/stable/current/) but these downloads don't seem to include a rootfs tarball, which is what I'm looking for.

Are rootfs tarballs no longer being published for new builds anymore?